# How to fix the table width content independently?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix the width no matter of what the content is. But, the width of the table is changing according to it's content.  How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<style>
           table{width:25px; background:#66f;}
    </style>
    <table>
           <tr>
                   <td>sn</td>
                   <td style="width:20px;">Name</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff</td>
           </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>sn</td>
        <td style="width:20px;">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td style="word-break: break-all;">Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `table-layout: fixed;` and provide `width` to your `table` and `td` elements accordingly.

You should also use `word-wrap: break-word;` so that you don't get in trouble if you encounter a non-breaked string

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HRUzP/)

Answer (score 0):

you don't mentioned style class table with dot extension and it won't be called using class attribute.

Here is the code:

```
<style>
        .table{
          width:25px; background:#66f;
        }
</style>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
           <td>sn</td>
           <td style="width:20px;">Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```